# Android studio project navigator empty items

Tags: android, android-studio

Sometimes (very often) when I change current branch in AS the project navigator becomes like this.

Does anybody had the same problem and how to solve it?
Steps to reproduse:

1. open project : [image: correct list]
2. switched to another branch [image: branch selector]
3. got this [image: broken navigator]

Comment: Are you using Android Studio 2.3?

Comment: Yes, the latest stable version

Comment: What do you mean by "change current branch"?

Comment: Switch project's branch in VCS

Comment: I'm not clear on that. I think it would help to add the following to your question so that I can try to reproduce it: 1. Show a before screen. 2, List the steps you take, .e.g. click on this, click on that. 3. show after screen (which you have done already).

Comment: Updated question with steps

Comment: Refresh project structure and it will work. It sometimes happens also to me when changing branches via VersionControl plugin. It also depends how big is your project

Comment: Tried that, only full restart works

Comment: I've taken your steps and the error does not happen for me. Sorry.